# For/In Loop in java script

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I could understand what logic is going behind the condition inside the for loop but still i could not get whats going behind the screens. Is there any set of documentations to learn what are all the ways of putting parameters for a for loop !! ?

```
function getFieldNames(row) {

var FieldNames = []

for (var column in row) {
    if (!row.hasOwnProperty(column))
        continue;

    FieldNames.push(column);

}

return FieldNames
}
```

Thank You .!

Comment: [Google has some good answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+for+loop&oq=javascript+for+loop)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3schools has documentation, and you can learn and test your code on the site.:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Mozilla offers a more explicit defintion and gives examples:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Here is an article that goes into a lot of detail and might be helpful:
http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/

EDIT: I do see w3schools has some bad formatting and practices, but the general explanation of loops is correct, and easy for someone starting out to understand.

Comment: [W3Schools considered harmful...](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: Note to voters: W3Schools may not be the best resource, but it is not entirely incorrect and [is not blacklisted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87680/15031).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski the point behind not blacklisting w3s is that voters should decide. We do.

Comment: Didn't realize that W3schools had the reputation. I used it a lot while starting out, and it seems alright for basic info, especially something as simple as loops.

Comment: @JanDvorak K. Giving fair warning about its accuracy is fine (as ach did). Punishing for just mentioning it isn't.

Comment: For one, they use `document.write`. Also, `br`. Also, they shun whitespace. And that's only the page directly linked here.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski this answer isn't "just mentioning" w3schools. It's the core of this answer - and the answer actively rates w3schools as good.

Comment: w3s is not entirely incorrect, but nor is a russian roulette entirely harmful.

Comment: @spacebean and yet they manage to propagate `document.write` as well as poor indentation while explaining said loops. And even introduce factual errors at a rate of approximately one per page.

Comment: i needed clarifications about for..in loops @spacebean

Comment: @PrasannaGira https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FStatements#Loop_Statements